# PyQt: Center QPainter text with drawText in QPrinter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter, qprinter

I am trying to focus the text on a normal A4 size folio, the sizes obtained are correct but it is not centered and I do not know what the reason is, here I show you the code

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPrinter,QPainter,QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt,QRectF
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

printer = QPrinter()
painter = QPainter()

printer.setOutputFileName("prueba.pdf")
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)

printer.setPageMargins(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1)
printer.setFullPage(True)
margin = printer.getPageMargins(1)
print margin
size = printer.paperSize(1)
width = size.width()
print width

painter.begin(printer)
painter.drawText(QRectF(0.0,0.0,width,50.0),Qt.AlignCenter|Qt.AlignTop,"abcdefghijklmn")
painter.end()
```

As you can see I get the width of the size of a folio type point and putting the entire width of the folio does not fit evenly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QPrinter` uses different types of [units of measure](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprinter.html#Unit-enum):

> **QPrinter.Unit**
>
> This enum type is used to specify the measurement unit for page and paper sizes.
>
> ```
> Constant  Value
> QPrinter.Millimeter   0
> QPrinter.Point        1
> QPrinter.Inch         2
> QPrinter.Pica         3
> QPrinter.Didot        4
> QPrinter.Cicero       5
> QPrinter.DevicePixel  6
> ```

When you get the size through the [`paperSize()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprinter.html#paperSize-2) method you are asking for it in `QPrinter.Point` units, but `QPainter` uses the coordinates in pixels, that is, `QPrinter.DevicePixel` so the obtained width is different from the width in pixels, to solve that if we just change the type of units of measurement as shown below:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

printer = QPrinter()
painter = QPainter()

printer.setOutputFileName("prueba.pdf")
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)

printer.setPageMargins(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, QPrinter.Point)
printer.setFullPage(True)
margin = printer.getPageMargins(QPrinter.Point)
print(margin)
size = printer.paperSize(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
width = size.width()
print(width)

painter.begin(printer)
painter.drawText(QRectF(0.0,0.0,width,50.0), Qt.AlignCenter|Qt.AlignTop, "abcdefghijklmn")
painter.end()
```